# Is it effective/efficient to use jQuery with OOP JS, and if so, how do I create a changing-state menu across class functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm trying to write a JavaScript `widget` in object-oriented JavaScript, or at least what I understand JS' near-equivalent of classes to be.

All I'm trying to achieve is a menu which changes state. In pseudo;

- Upon widget load, populate `#nav` with a `<ul>` menu containing *year group* `<li>`s.
- Upon clicking a year group `<li>`, empty `#nav ul` of its `<li>` and re-populate it with *tutor group*  `<li>`s in that year, as well as appending a `return` link.
- Upon clicking the `return` link, empty `#nav` and re-populate it with the original *year group* `<ul>` menu whilst being able to utilise all of the above functionality.

**Historically**, i.e. to date, I've used "embedded" functions to try and keep everything within the same DOM layer/timing. I don't really understand how any of this works, or if this is an appropriate thing to do, but the code itself seemed to work.

Here's an example of the way I've done it previously:

```
var GroupsDisplayHTML = '<h2>Tutor Groups</h2>' +
    '<ul><li><a class="year" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Year 9" id="9">Year 9</a></li>' +
    '<li><a class="year" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Year 10" id="10">Year 10</a></li>' +
    '<li><a class="year" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Year 11" id="11">Year 11</a></li>' +
    '<li><a class="year" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Year 12" id="12">Year 12</a></li>' +
    '<li><a class="year" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Year 13" id="13">Year 13</a></li></ul>';

$("div#groups").html(GroupsDisplayHTML);

$('a.year').click( function() {
    var Groups;
    var Groups_Sorted = [];

    Frog.API.get('groups.getAll',
    {
        'onSuccess': function (data) { Groups = data; },
        'onError': function(err) { alert(err); }
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < Groups.length; i++) {
        var Year = $(this).attr("id");

        if (Groups[i].name.indexOf(Year) == 0 && Groups[i].name.indexOf('/Tp') != -1) {
            var arrayToPush = { 'id': Groups[i].id, 'name': Groups[i].name };
            Groups_Sorted.push(arrayToPush);
        }
    }

    GroupsDisplayHTML = '<h2>Year ' + Year + '</h2><ul>';

    for(var i = 0; i < Groups_Sorted.length; i++){
        GroupsDisplayHTML += '<li><a class="group" href="javascript:void(0);" title="' + Groups_Sorted[i].id + '" id="' + Groups_Sorted[i].id + '">' + 
            Groups_Sorted[i].name + ' <span style="font-size:10px;color:#bbb;">(' + Groups_Sorted[i].name + ')</span></a></li>';
    }

    GroupsDisplayHTML += '<li><a class="return" href="javascript:void(0);">&lt;- Back to Year Groups</a></li></ul>';

    $("div#groups").html(GroupsDisplayHTML);

    $('a.group').click( function() {
        var Group_ID = $(this).attr("id");
        AssignPoints.getUsers(Group_ID);
    });

    $('a.return').click( function() {
        AssignPoints.displayGroups(data);
    });
});
```

---

However, now, I'm wondering if the better way to do it is to use jQuery's **`on`** function. Here's the code I'm currently writing (*just to try and achieve the changing-state menu):

```
var TutorGroupPoints = {
    URL: 'http://staff.curriculum.local/frog/rewards.php',
    currentUser: UWA.Environment.user.id,
    groupsObject: { },
    sortedArray: [ ],
    navHTML: '<h2>Tutor Groups</h2>' +
        '<ul>' +
            '<li><a class="year" title="Year 9" id="9">Year 9</a></li>' +
            '<li><a class="year" title="Year 10" id="10">Year 10</a></li>' +
            '<li><a class="year" title="Year 11" id="11">Year 11</a></li>' +
            '<li><a class="year" title="Year 12" id="12">Year 12</a></li>' +
            '<li><a class="year" title="Year 13" id="13">Year 13</a></li>' +
        '</ul>',

    init: function() {
        /* caching outer this -> AJAX scope problems */
        var that = this;

        /* retrieve all of the user groups from Frog VLE and store them in an object-level variable */
        Frog.API.get('groups.getAll',
        {
            'onSuccess': function (data) { that.groupsObject = data; },
            'onError': function(err) { alert(err); }
        });

        /* populate the div#nav with our year group UL */
        $('#nav').append(this.navHTML);

        /* using "on" because the LIs have been created in the DOM? */
        $('#nav ul').on("click", "li a", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            that.yearClick( $(this).attr("id") );
        });
    },

    yearClick: function(year) {
        /* run through groupsObject and pull out any tutor groups found in the year we've clicked on
           then put those into our sortedArray */
        for (var i = 0; i < this.groupsObject.length; i++) {
            if (this.groupsObject[i].name.indexOf(year) == 0 && this.groupsObject[i].name.indexOf('/Tp') != -1) {
                /* all we need is name and id */
                var arrayToPush = { 'id': this.groupsObject[i].id, 'name': this.groupsObject[i].name };
                this.sortedArray.push(arrayToPush);
            }
        }

        /* clear the existing UL from div#nav */
        $('#nav ul').empty();

        /* populate div#nav's UL with LIs of our tutor groups (label being name, attr="id" being id) and
           clickable links for each */
        for (var i = 0; i < this.sortedArray.length; i++) {
            $('#nav ul').append('<li><a class="tutor" id="' + this.sortedArray[i].id + '">' + this.sortedArray[i].name + '</a></li>');
        }

        /* add a "return" link to view other years' tutor groups */
        $('#nav ul').append('<li><a id="return">&lt;- Return</a></li>');

        /* upon clicking the return link, empty #nav ul then re-append our navHTML from earlier */
        $('#nav ul').on("click", "a#return", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#nav ul').empty();
            $('#nav').append(this.navHTML);
        });

        /* upon clicking any of our tutor group LIs, display that link's id so that we can use it in
           another function to actually display some content */
        $('#nav ul').on("click", "a.tutor", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert( $(this).attr("id") );
        });
    }

};

widget.onLoad = function(){
    /* run our "class" */
    TutorGroupPoints.init();
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav">

    </div>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
</div>
```

I've created a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/byzgv/1/), which is a slight manipulation of the code (i.e. I've removed the inaccessible Frog API calls and replaced them with a fixed object). Hopefully this works adequately.

**The problem here is that once I click the return button, nothing happens**. In addition, I suspect that fixing the return button would then provide me with some links which, when clicked upon, would do nothing.

**Ideally**, as per the bottom end of the code, I would like to run *another function within my TutorGroupPoints class* when the user clicks on a specific tutor group. How will this affect my return button, etc? Will they then stop working because they aren't being run from the "current" function?

More than "just" an answer to my code problems, I'd quite like some *direction*, i.e. is the recent code I've written better than the older stuff? Should I be using `on` or should I be using embedded jQuery functions and communicative class functions?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with OOP, it is about normal event handlers vs. live/delegated event handlers (or, in pure Javascript terms, handling the event at the element where it happens vs. handling it on some parent element via event bubbling). Delegating is certainly more effective; whether the difference is large enough that you should care is another question, and depends on the usage patterns of your application.

Comment: Sorry @Tgr I've added a small paragraph explaining that I'd like the final click to run another function within my class, and I was wondering how that would affect the "state" of my menu and its functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: http://jsfiddle.net/byzgv/4/

I'm not sure about the OOP aspect, but this seems to be your scenario:

1. when the page is loaded, you insert a list into a div.
2. you add some event handlers to this list
3. you click a list item, your event handlers run, and change the list items.
4. the "Return" list item "does nothing" when you click it.

In your fiddle, clicking the "Return" list item *does* do something, it empties this list. This is partly what you asked it to do:

```
$('#nav').on("click", "ul a#return", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#nav ul').empty();
    $('#nav').append(this.navHTML);
});
```

So this event handler has fired, and the first two instructions have worked. The call to `append` doesn't work because you're in a different context - `this` does not refer to the TutorGroupPoints object. So you can fix this by referring to your object explicitly:

```
$('#nav').on("click", "ul a#return", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#nav ul').empty();
    $('#nav').append(TutorGroupPoints.navHTML);
});
```

(by the way, you're appending a whole new list, so you need to do `$('#nav').empty();` instead of `$('#nav ul').empty();`)

Then, as you guessed, clicking the "Return" item gives you a new list which doesn't respond to click events. This is because of how you're calling the `on` function. The jQuery object you call `on` on must exist when the event handler is being set up. In your `init` function, the list does exist when you set up the event handlers, as you're appending it to the `div` before calling `on`. But later, you trash this list and replace it.

To get your event handlers working on all lists rather than just the first one, you need to attach your event handlers to an element that exists from the start and doesn't change, i.e. the `#nav` div. So

```
$('#nav ul').on("click", "li a", function(e) {
```

can become

```
$('#nav').on("click", "ul li a", function(e) {
```

Comment: I've realised that clicking subsequent years in the list keeps appending items to the list that gets shown, but I'm sure you can sort that out ;)

Comment: Ah, Graham, that's a superb explanation. Makes a great deal of sense, thank you very much.

Comment: I've managed to fix the re-appending, but I can't understand why I get multiple alerts! http://jsfiddle.net/byzgv/6/ Any ideas?

Comment: @dunc - this is because you're setting up some of your event handlers (i.e. calling `on`) in your `yearClick` function, and you're calling this function multiple times. So the same event handler is being created many times over. You only need to create the event handlers once, in your `init` function. See http://jsfiddle.net/byzgv/7/